# python looping for image processing using gdal and database catalogue

Tags: python, image-processing, gdal

I am a novice in python and all i want is to create a loop that executes the following command and if the hDataset open is sucessful to the next process

```
hDataset = gdal.Open( pszFilename, gdal.GA_ReadOnly )
if hDataset is None:
   print some condition
else:
   print somecondition.
```

the next process utilizes the `hDataset` if it opened successfully otherwise it should continue looping until `hDataset` is successfully opened and pass it to the next process.

Comment: properly indenting is mandatory in Python.

Comment: Please clarify: "if the result is true". What result?

Comment: if the dataset opened sucesfully then the dataset whould be passed for more processed like gdalwarp and other

Comment: looping over what? a list of files?